# Http Response contains only first character entered into HttpServletResponse.getWriter

Tags: java, servlets, printwriter

Im currently writing a servlet that should allow the user to write custom rest endpoints. The endpoints produce a `RestResponse` object which i am trying to convert into the final `HTTPServletResponse` Object.
The `RestResponse` contains a `org.json.simple.JSONObject` representing the Response Body. I now need to get this Object into the Body of of the HTTP Response.

My Idea is to use the `PrintWriter` of the `HTTPServletResponse`, According to the Debugger the entire `JSONObject` ends Up in the `CharBuffer` of the `PrintWriter` as it should, however in the final HTTP Response Body inside my Browser there is only the first character.

`rest` is my `RestResponse` object and `http` is my `HTTPServletResponse` Object (coming unchanged since handed into the `doGet` Method of the servlet)

I tried to use various different methods like:

```java
if (rest.hasBody()) {
   //TODO this somehow fails to write a valid JSON String to the HTTP Body
   PrintWriter writer = http.getWriter();
   rest.getBody().writeJSONString(writer);
   //Here the proper json string ends in the buffer of the writer
   writer.flush();
   writer.close();
}
```

```java
if (rest.hasBody()) {
   //TODO this somehow fails to write a valid JSON String to the HTTP Body
   PrintWriter writer = http.getWriter();
   writer.write(rest.getBody.toJSONString());
   //Here the proper json string ends in the buffer of the writer
   writer.flush();
   writer.close();
}
```

```java
if (rest.hasBody()) {
   //TODO this somehow fails to write a valid JSON String to the HTTP Body
   PrintWriter writer = http.getWriter();
   writer.append(rest.getBody.toJSONString());
   //Here the proper json string ends in the buffer of the writer
   writer.flush();
   writer.close();
}
```

and so on, everything gives the same result

I've been debugging this for several hours now and i still didn't figure out whats wrong, does anybody have an idea?

Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So my issue was that somehow i set `http.setContentlength(variable)` where variable accidentally was 1, therefor apparently the body will only contain the first character.